# Selenium test not accessing URL?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium test with the goal of testing whether or not windows authentication works on a site. Since the test cases I was writing before didn't involve me directly testing whether or not windows authentication was working, I was appending the username and password to the URL to get around the windows authentication completely (e.g. https://username:password@blah.com). Now the goal is to test windows authentication on the site and when I try to hit the URL without appending the username and password, selenium fails to hit the URL and displays a blank page. What is the reason for this?

```
string URL = "https://blah.com"
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
//displays a blank page without any windows authentication popup
```

Comment: You mean to say the driver navigated to url but the response page is blank?What is the behaviour when you manually hit the url in browser?

Comment: chrome just opens with "data;" in the search bar and displays a blank page. When I hit the url manually, the windows authentication popup displays as expected.

Comment: Have you created an object for driver?

Comment: Yes I instantiate a driver and a chrome browser window opens just with "data;" in the search bar displaying a blank page.